# Apriltag pose detection on curved surface

Tags: opencv, pose-estimation, apriltags, fiducial-markers

I am using apriltag to detect fiducial markers and estimate the pose of the marker. I intend to use the markers on curved surfaces however apriltag seems to not be able to estimate curved markers very successfully (e.g. on a coffee mug). Is there any way I could try of estimating the pose of a marker on a curved surface? I have seen some custom markers that are designed for curved surfaces but the code isn't open source.

[image]

The above gif is an example I recorded of apriltag struggling with curved surfaces.

Comment: it's not made for curved surfaces. it assumes that all four sides present as straight lines. if you need curved markers to work, you'll need a detector that _expects_ curved surfaces.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz as I feared, yes. I've had a look for curved markers, but it seems as if most are proprietary. Instead, I've found a method that doesn't make use of curved surfaces in the meantime. Thank you for your answer.